# Adding Log4J appenders programmatically

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jboss6.x

Ok, so I have this stupid library I'm using (documentum DFC), which does a check to see if `Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders().hasMoreElements() == false`, if so, it resets my rootLogger level to `WARN`, which destroys my logging after that.  So in an effort to stop this, I'm attempting to add an appender to the root logger just to see if I can get it to stop doing that code.  However when 
I call

`Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new ConsoleAppender());` that function is still coming up false.  Has anyone run into this?

I'm using whatever log4j version comes with jboss 6, it doesn't say in the jar file name.

Comment: Maybe log4j is being loaded from two different classloaders, so you have two different root loggers? Or maybe some other code is removing the appender after you add it?

Comment: @user428916: If you want to check for false value do not `==` operator. Just use it like this `if(!Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders().hasMoreElements())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have similar problems. I can add an appender, writing to a memory string but this never works.
For me it seems like JBoss does use/modify log4J in a way, that this code modification is no longer possible, see also here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-9318